# Install JUnit with Oracle Java 7 already instaled

Tags: 12.10, java, oracle

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 with Oracle Java 7 installed (as described [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux)). I want to install JUnit 4 but if I do a simple `sudo apt-get install junit`, it starts to download openjdk and the like (which I don't want). How to manually do it? And from where do I download and install.

Please help!

Comment: I guess that happens because Oracle Java is not present on the repositories, so it tries to install one available. JUnit is basically a .jar, so you can add it to your projects. See [this](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Download-and-Install).

Comment: So I have to download junit.jar and hamcrest-core.jar and put them in `/usr/share/java`?

Comment: ^ That didn't work

Comment: Umm what? My problem isn't solved. I said *didn't*

Comment: Sorry :) What I was saying before is that if you are using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans you can add that jar to each project you need.

Comment: I need it to build LibreOffice. Not for Eclipse projects.

Comment: Are you using the command line to build LibreOffice? If so, what command(s) are you using?

Comment: Initially I did a `sudo apt-get build-dep libreoffice` which started installing open jdk. I already had Oracle Java 7 installed and I didn't want to mess it up. I cloned the git repo, ran autogen.sh and installed the dependencies as and when the script complained. I'm stuck at Junit now. For LibreOffice, I followed this link. https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Native_Build

Comment: Suggest you follow Salem's answer below then run `sudo apt-get build-dep libreoffice` again.

Comment: I have given up, installed openjdk, intalled junit. Then, it still cried no junit. Ran it with a --without-junit flag and got over with it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Oracle JDK is not availabe in the default repositories, it is not listed in the dependencies or jUnit. So to "install" it you have to download the .jar's and place them where Oracle JRE could find them.

Supposing you installed JRE on `/usr/local/java` the correct place should be `/usr/local/java/jdk<version>/jre/lib`. So a command like this should suffice:

```
sudo cp /path/to/junit_jars/*.jar /usr/local/java/jdk<version>/jre/lib
```

And for Junit you have to just include the jar into your program classpath. You can download the jar from [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Download-and-Install).

Comment: Marked solved because I learnt how to install Junit